# Package manager says I have the latest version but there is a newer one

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to to install [libgsf-1-114](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgsf&searchon=names&suite=disco&section=all) package which according to the packages.ubuntu the latest version is 1.14.45-1.
Currently I have version 1.14.36-1:

```
apt list libgsf-1-114
Listing... Done
libgsf-1-114/xenial,now 1.14.36-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

But if I try to upgrade, I get:

```
sudo apt-get -s upgrade libgsf-1-114 | grep libgsf
libgsf-1-114 is already the newest version (1.14.36-1).
libgsf-1-114 set to manually installed.
```

I've tried setting it to auto, but it keeps saying its manually installed (if that makes any difference)

```
sudo apt-mark auto libgsf-1-114
libgsf-1-114 was already set to automatically installed.
```

I actually want to upgrade to a specific version and not to the latest but it looks like the package manager just can't find a newer version

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? That is the latest version for 16.04 (Xenial).

Comment: Thank you @kemotep, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (inside Windows), where can I see the latest package version per ubuntu version?

Comment: ***I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (inside Windows),***: Is it WSL?

Comment: @Kulfy yes it is..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your version of Ubuntu (**16.04**), that is the latest package version.  As per your own link, if you want that particular version, you need to upgrade to:

> **disco (19.04)** (libs): Structured File Library - runtime version

If you want the latest package version for your version of Ubuntu, use this link:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=szPackageName&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

Where you change `szPackageName` by the package you're looking for.